# Adding a border to anchor hover state without affecting remainder of items

Tags: html, css

I want to add a border on the left and right hand side of the hovered item in my navigation. This works, but seeing that I am adding 2px to the element it pushes the other elements out. How can I add the border to almost be on the inside of the hovered a list item without it affecting the remainder of the navigation?

```
 // Simple example:
 li {
     list-style: none;
     display: inline;
 }

 li a:hover {
     border-left: 1px solid black;
     border-right: 1px solid black;
 }

 // HTML:
 <ul>
     <li><a href="">Test 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Test 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Test 2</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Or visit [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/95ZUw/) for an active example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a transparent border to your `a` tags:

```
li a {
    border: 1px transparent solid;
    border-width: 0 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/95ZUw/1/

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution, but ... add 1px padding and then remove it when hover is triggered. Its possible in your case to do that?

```
li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
}

li > a { padding:0 1px; }

li a:hover {
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
padding:0;
}
```